# Cant figure out why I am getting this Kramdownn warning

Tags: kramdown

Previously, I had this text being processed by Kramdown without any problems:

```
* **[GIT]**  Setup a git repo for your team
```

Recently I started getting this error:

```
kramdown warning: No link definition for link ID 'git' found on line 4
```

I can't see in the Kramdown revision history that this is now an invalid input and before I got and modify hundreds of files I wonder whether anyone can shed light on this, and in also how I can modify the line most easily. What I want is a that the text "[GIT]" appear in bold on a bulleted line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an invalid input. kramdown will correctly parse that as expected (as of version 1.6.0):

```
<ul>
    <li><strong>[GIT]</strong>  Setup a git repo for your team</li>
</ul>
```

I'm not sure why the warnings were suppressed earlier, but I checked through the Ruby code and that warning was present in the earliest available version. I also checked back to 1.3.3 and it also generates that warning.

Even though kramdown generates the desired output, if you want to avoid the warning, you can escape the brackets.

```
* **\[GIT\]**  Setup a git repo for your team
```